# WPF: Update mousepointer when UI thread is blocked

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, blocking, repaint

I have some task that's freezing the UI for a few seconds, and in this specific case I have no other choice than execute it from the UI thread (normally I use Dispatchers).

I completely understand that my window cannot repaint itself during this time, but how do I force the mousepointer to redraw itself before executing the blocking call? Right now I do:

```
Me.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait
[Heavy Task]
Me.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Default
```

But the window does not update the cursor to a wait-cursor, because the UI thread is frozen? How do I force the update?

Comment: Reconsider executing the task on the UI thread

Comment: @FactorMystic Did you read anything I wrote?

Comment: of course I did, but I'm suggesting pivoting to address why you can't get long running work off of the UI thread

Comment: It's not a long running work (2 secs max), but it's calling a database component that's not thread-safe, and it will be much more work rewriting that component, than simply forcing the right cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I have found the solution. Instead of changing the cursor for the window, overide it globally:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
[Heavy Task]
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Default;
```